# How can I measure the cumulative network usage of a process, from execution beginning to end

Tags: linux, networking, bash, linux-networking, wireshark

I want to measure how much bandwidth `git pull` uses, preferably by prefixing git command with desired program, i.e. `nettally git pull`

Alternatively, is there some sneaky way to accumulate nethogs / wireshark data and add up the figures after execution?

Thanks

Comment: If i were to do this, I would run `iftop` but that's not totally suitable for your needs.

Comment: yeah, you know all these programs do the same thing. nethogs, wireshark, iftop. Is it possible to run the app on it's own interface maybe?

Comment: Another trick would be an iptables "mangle" rule maybe ? then you have counters... but that's still far from what you want.

Comment: Have a look at http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/, I think it does what you want.

Answer (score 22):

If you launch `nethogs` and then press the <kbd>m</kbd> key, it will switch from instantaneous mode (kB/s) to cumulative mode (kB).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the command in a SOCKS client (eg. dante-client), point SOCKS at a server (eg. socat/netcat) which will measure traffic and forward to the real SOCKS server. There will be a SOCKS overhead, but presuming you don't need an *exact* measure then just factor this in.

A shell script could set up the socat sockets and LD_PRELOAD_PATH environment, run the command and report stats once done.